# The import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64Encoder cannot be resolved

Tags: java

I've imported jar file as a project in Eclipse. After doing the import, I'm getting this issue "The import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64Encoder cannot be resolved".

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have jar file and class `org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64Encoder` in **Referenced Libraries**:
[image: Screen shot in Project Explorer]

Comment: @SumitSonawane it's not my answer but Đức Trần Trung's, I just corrected formatting. But if it helped you, mark it as accepted and consider upvoting if you can